# open cart install and second time run this error popup

Tags: php, mysqli, opencart

How to fix this errors in open cart?

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045):
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 7

Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct():
Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 10

Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct():
Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
'Error: <br />Error No: ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db.php(9): DB\MySQLi->__construct('localhost', 'root', '', 'opencart', '3306')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\system\framework.php(80): DB->__construct('mysqli', 'localhost', 'root', '', 'opencart', '3306') 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\system\startup.php(104): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\index.php(19): start('catalog')
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 10
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: It looks like you entered the bad DB credentials in your config.

Comment: Check your Database credentials